# Has anyone successfully implemented Azure Active Directory B2C for auth using Microsoft.Identity.Client 1.1.0-preview?

Tags: xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

I have been struggling with this for several days (three actually). I have AAD B2C working on a web app and an api. I cannot get it running on my Xamarin mobile project. I am using the UWP project to test my configuration since it has the easiest app to troubleshoot on a Windows 10 machine. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Pro.

I am using the Microsoft.Identity.Client 1.1.0-preview.
I used this as my starting point for my attempt to implement.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

Right now the project will compile and launch. When I click on Sign in, I get a WebView, but it doesn't look exactly right....
[First Image in Screenshots]

Here are my variables...

```
public class Constants
{
public static string ApplicationID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
public static string[] Scopes = {""};
public static string SignUpSignInPolicy = "B2C_1_Standard_SignUpSignIn";
public static string ResetPasswordPolicy = "B2C_1_Standard_PasswordReset";
public static string EditProfilePolicy = "B2C_1_Standard_EditProfile";

public static string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[MyTennantName].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Standard_SignUpSignIn";
public static string AuthorityEditProfile = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[MyTennantName].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Standard_EditProfile";

public static string ApiEndpoint = "https://[MyTennantName].onmicrosoft.com/apiservices";

public static UIParent UiParent = null;
}
```

My Login method is....

```
async void OnSignInSignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (btnSignInSignOut.Text == "Sign in")
        {
            AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, Constants.SignUpSignInPolicy), Constants.UiParent);
            UpdateUserInfo(ar);
            UpdateSignInState(true);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var user in App.PCA.Users)
            {
                App.PCA.Remove(user);
            }
            UpdateSignInState(false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Checking the exception message 
        // should ONLY be done for B2C
        // reset and not any other error.
        if (ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            OnPasswordReset();
        // Alert if any exception excludig user cancelling sign-in dialog
        else if (((ex as MsalException)?.ErrorCode != "authentication_canceled"))
            await DisplayAlert($"Exception:", ex.ToString(), "Dismiss");
    }
}
```

However before I can even enter my password I get the following....
[Second image in Screenshots]

My application definition looks like this...[Third image in screenshots]

I don't think it is recognizing my tenant and trying to log me in with a Microsoft account. I have double checked my Tenant name and Application ID.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AsSI.jpg)

I don't have enough reputation to post more than one link and one picture.

Also, the Azure AD B2C api application works for a web app. I have created a web app that can authenticate and works with the API.

Comment: Your Authority endpoints are not quite correct as they are missing /tfp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like while modifying the authorization value in the Sample you removed the /tfp/ part.

You should update your values as follows:

```
   public static string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/[MyTennantName].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Standard_SignUpSignIn";
   public static string AuthorityEditProfile = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/[MyTennantName].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Standard_EditProfile";
```

Comment: Awesome. That fixed it! I'm back in business!

Comment: Hey Steve, can you please flag this question as answered? Thanks!